# Two gateways on same network

Tags: networking, server, gateway

My machine runs Ubuntu Server 16.04 and it has two NICs, eth0 and eth1, as shown in the network diagram.
Its role was initially to route traffic from the 192.168.50.0/24 subnet to the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet where the DSL router is that connects to the internet.
So my network configuration is

Output of (eth0) `cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0`

```
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

Output of (eth1) `cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1`

```
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.50.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Now I added another cellular router which also connects to the internet, and it's connected on the 192.168.50.0/24 subnet. 
I need to route some of the internet traffic through that cellular router, but not all of it (e.g. ssh connections)
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

[image: Network diagram]

Comment: Just some idea (no solution):  Have 192.168.50.7 as default router for your clients, and configure firewall there to reroute according to your demand.

Comment: Use the `route` command to add routes for specific destinations to use the other subnet.

Comment: Ok but I can't see how to do this for only a specific application (e.g. ssh running on port 22)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we shall take `ssh` as the service for routing. Use `mangle` table of iptable for modifying the `ssh` packets.

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```

We are marking all packets with destination port `22` as `0x1` .

Now save and restart `iptables`.

```
sudo service iptables save
sudo service iptables restart
```

Next, create a new IP route table in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` by just giving an entry

```
100 sshtable
```

Write rule for `ssh` packets.

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 lookup sshtable
```

Add route at new table `sshtable`. All other traffic will go through the
default gateway, which can be seen by `ip route show` command.

We copy all entries except default gateway entry from main table.

```
sudo ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table sshtable $ROUTE; done
```

Add default gateway entry for `ssh` packets to table `sshtable`

```
sudo ip route add default gw 192.168.50.254 table sshtable
```

Use `ip route show table sshtable` to show all routes at `sshtable`.

Try.